# Python Routes issues using Flask

Tags: python, flask, routes

I have the following function with multiple routes possible :

```
@bp.route('/list/', defaults={'status': None, 'time': None, 'search': None})
@bp.route('/list/lot/', defaults={'status': None, 'search': None, 'time': None})
@bp.route('/list/lot/<string:time>/', defaults={'status': None, 'search': None})
@bp.route('/list/lot/<string:time>/<string:status>', defaults={'search': None})
@bp.route('/list/lot/<string:time>/<string:status>?search=<path:search>')
@login_required
def index(status, time, search):
    print(search)
```

All the routes works well, except the last one. I have the URL likes this :

```
http://192.168.10.88:5000/list/lot/OLDER/NEW?search=test
```

And I don't understand why, the print always return `None`.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: I think, you should get the **search** data through `request`. Not in function argument. Just import `from flask import request` and then `request.args.get('search')` inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `request` or `request.query_string` if you want to get the query string:

```
from flask import request

@bp.route('/list/', defaults={'status': None, 'time': None, 'search': None})
@bp.route('/list/lot/', defaults={'status': None, 'search': None, 'time': None})
@bp.route('/list/lot/<string:time>/', defaults={'status': None, 'search': None})
@bp.route('/list/lot/<string:time>/<string:status>', defaults={'search': None})
@bp.route('/list/lot/<string:time>/<string:status>?search=<path:search>')
@login_required
def index(status, time, search):
    print(request.query_string, request.args.get('search'), time, status)
    #  b'search=test' test OLDER NEW
    return 'OK'
```

remarks how I used `request` to get the value of search : `request.args.get('search')`.

Here is another approach that I find simpler and cleaner:

```
@bp.route('/list/lot/parameters')
@login_required
def index():
    print(request.args.get('time'), request.args.get('status'), request.args.get('search'))
    return 'OK'
```

The Url look like this:

```
http://192.168.10.88:5000/list/lot/parameters?time=OLDER&status=NEW&search=test
```

Answer (score 1):

The part after the `?` is the query string. I'm 99% sure Flask strips the query string off when matching routes (I couldn't confirm this in the docs hence the 1%). This means that the following urls are identical when matching a route.

```
http://192.168.10.88:5000/list/lot/OLDER/NEW?search=test
http://192.168.10.88:5000/list/lot/OLDER/NEW
```

Another way to do what (I think) you are trying to do is use the query string for all your variables.

```
@bp.route('/list/')
@bp.route('/list/lot/')
@login_required
def index():
    status = request.args.get('status', default=None)
    time = request.args.get('time', default=None)
    search = request.args.get('search', default=None)

    print(search)
```